# Creating product pages using PHP

Tags: php

I have a product gallery page, with numerous products.

I wish to create a page for each product with product specific comment box(maybe facebook). I can write a new page for each product and hyperlink them. But this will need a new page for every product added.

I think I can use php to dynamically create a page for every product out in a layout previously defined.

Can anybody help with a basic example??

Comment: your question is too vague. Please show us what you tried, what you already found, what is precisely your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most basic of examples:

```
<?php
echo "Page for product #{$_GET['id']}";
```

Try accessing the PHP page with `page_name.php?id=1234`.